# Add condition to select only images between 1 day and 2 days difference

Tags: google-earth-engine, attribute-joins

I want to compute the difference in chloa concentration at an interval of 2 days.
I used this function to create a join with the images from a date range of 2 days but I only want to select images with a difference between 1 & 2 days :

```
var Modis_saveAll = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.Join.saveAll({matchesKey: 'diff',   ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
    .apply({
      primary: Modis_chloa, 
      secondary: Modis_chloa,
      condition: ee.Filter.and(
        ee.Filter.maxDifference({
          difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2, // Max 2 days difference
          leftField: 'system:time_start',
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        }),
        ee.Filter.greaterThan({
          leftField:'system:time_start', 
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        })
      )
    })
```

Doo you have an idea of a condition to add on the join or a function to map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another filter to the AND for maxDifference up to 1 day and negate that one (with .not())

```
ee.Filter.and(
        ee.Filter.maxDifference({
          difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2, // Max 2 days difference
          leftField: 'system:time_start',
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        }),
        ee.Filter.greaterThan({
          leftField:'system:time_start', 
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        }),
        ee.Filter.maxDifference({
          difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1, // Max 1 day difference
          leftField: 'system:time_start',
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        }).not()
)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot I did not know the existence of the .not() function ! It's very helpfull !